# Is it necessary to create tables like AspNetUsers while adding JWT authentication to ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to create a simple ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API to serve data from an `SQL Server` database. I want to use JWT-based bearer authentication for access to the API via simple `username` and `password` credentials, nothing too complex. So far, I have been able to create a simple Core 2.1 Web API project with non-authenticated CRUD operations enabled, but adding JWT support to it is proving to be a little problematic.

My database has a table called `Users` which houses personal information of the users, which includes `username` and `password hash` fields. I want to use this same table for JWT based authentication. However, most of the tutorials on the topic (like [this](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/june/token-based-authentication-in-aspnet-core-part-1/)) use the concept of migration which adds several tables (e.g. `AspNetUserTokens` and `AspNetUserLogins`) to my database, which seems pretty useless to me as I do not plan on using external authentication like Google or Facebook. Even the table `AspNetUsers` contains seemingly redundant fields.

I also tried following [this tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/26/aspnet-core-21-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management) with in-memory datastore but couldn't implement SQL Server integration to it (facing a lot of errors like `Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager'` and `Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' this type is not included in the model for the context`).

Can I add JWT-based authentication to an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API with SQL Server database integration without the migration procedure (especially in the context of [this project](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/26/aspnet-core-21-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management))?

Comment: This guide might help you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/27/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/ (I haven't the time to provide an answer at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I add JWT-based authentication to an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API with
>   SQL Server database integration without the migration procedure (especially in the context of this project)?

**Yes**, you can. 
You don't need to use IdentityServer (*and it's migration process*) just because you're handling user data. 
You can perfectly fine create your own implementation of the user handling as the one in this [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/26/aspnet-core-21-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management)

---

To add the SQL Server integration, look at the StartUp.cs class in the linked project, this line

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"));
```

Change that line and point out your database connectionstring

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer("yourConnectionstring"));
```

Comment: I used the same way and got it to work by some minor troubleshooting afterwards. Thank you.